# Is it not possible to have multiply OwinStartup attributes?

Tags: owin

In a CMS where multiply packages might provide owin startup attributes, is there a way to create multiply startups classes?

If not I will have to create a startup class where package creaters can register their owin startup class and the cms startup class will take care of running these. But then if someone in a package puts in a startup attribute, it might be that his got run and not the cms startup.

Are there any way I can tell that my startup is the most important so that will run over all others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have multiple startup classes in an application and instruct the runtime to choose one of those. Multiple Owinstartup attributes can be declared with different friendly names and pass in the friendly name of the corresponding Startup class to be used using the appSetting owin:AppStartup. [Here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) is a detailed documentation on how to have multiple startup attributes.

Comment: but thats still one attribute with multiply startup classes, yes?

Comment: this is multiple attributes and multiple startup classes. This is precisely for the scenario where the same application can have different startup configurations for different environments. Say preprod with more logging enabled, and prod with less/no logging etc.

Comment: been over the document twice now. I dont see where it provide I can use two attributes. It only shows how I can specify two startups in the same attribute.

Comment: [assembly: OwinStartup("startup1", typeof(Startup1))] public class Startup1 {...} [assembly: OwinStartup ("startup2", typeof())] public class Startup2 { ... } with appSetting owin:AppStartup value="startup1 OR startup2" will pick appropriate startup class.

Comment: In this document refer to topic "Add More Startup Classes" steps 1 - 8. You can have multiple assembly level OwinStartup attributes. If you use VS 2013 item template for creating OWINStartup class, then you item template will also add the attribute in the same code file. While adding multiple just specify a friendly name in the attribute as the first parameter.

Comment: okay thanks. I get it now. For my question, I needed not to pick one of the startup classes but unite them to one. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This answer also works same : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/introduction-of-owin-startup-class-in-visual-studio-2013-rc/

Comment: Can you please provide an example from the link to make your answer more complete?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I recently ran into this problem and here is how I solved it. I had a 3rd party library that used this OwinStartup method, but I also needed it to map SignalR routes. 
So I simply made a startup class that loops through all loaded assemblies and finds there startup classes and invokes them

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(TestWeb.Startup))]
namespace TestWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            foreach (Assembly startupAssembly in System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(assembly => assembly.GetCustomAttribute<OwinStartupAttribute>() != null))
            {
                OwinStartupAttribute startupAttribute = startupAssembly.GetCustomAttribute<OwinStartupAttribute>();
                if (startupAttribute.StartupType != typeof(TestWeb.Startup))
                {
                    object startupClass = Activator.CreateInstance(startupAttribute.StartupType);
                    string startupMethod = string.IsNullOrEmpty(startupAttribute.MethodName) ? "Configuration" : startupAttribute.MethodName;

                    startupAttribute.StartupType.GetMethod(startupMethod).Invoke(startupClass, new object[] { app });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if you don't need the IAppBuilder instance you could use the [WebActivatorEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/webactivatorex) instead